# How to vertically fill space between elements in ScrollView while preserving scrolling

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to achieve the following:
[image]

I tried achieving this with a GridLayout and only get one of the following two things working:

1. The space between the Label and the StackLayout is filled (label is
   stretched), but scrolling will not work when adding more labels into
   the StackLayout
2. Scrolling will work when more labels are added into
   the StackLayout, but when only one label is showed for example, the
   label before the StackLayout will not stretch

Is there any way to achieve such a thing? GridLayout is not necessarily needed, but I tried several ways and could not find any way of doing this.

example code of (1)

```
  <Page class="page dark">

      <ScrollView backgroundColor="red">

        <GridLayout rows="*, auto" height="100%" backgroundColor="blue">
          <Label backgroundColor="green">Top Label</Label>
          <StackLayout row="1" backgroundColor="green">
            <Label backgroundColor="purple">Label A</Label>
            <Label backgroundColor="purple">Label B</Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>

      </ScrollView>

  </Page>
```

example code of (2):

```
  <Page class="page dark">

      <ScrollView backgroundColor="red">

        <GridLayout rows="*, auto" backgroundColor="blue">
          <Label backgroundColor="green">Top Label</Label>
          <StackLayout row="1" backgroundColor="green">
            <Label backgroundColor="purple">Label A</Label>
            <Label backgroundColor="purple">Label B</Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>

      </ScrollView>

  </Page>
```

Comment: You mean, you need empty space between your label and stack layout?

Comment: @Manoj Yess, that is exactly what I meant :)

Comment: Looking at your images I think you should use Parallax scrolling here.

Comment: @Manoj can you please specify how to establish this?

Comment: Checkout [nativescript-parallax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-parallax) for examples

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve this for months and I finally found a working solution, for iOS and Android.

The solution is to use `FlexboxLayout` instead of `GridLayout`. When placed in a `ScrollView`, `FlexboxLayout` will take the whole available height if it is not tall enough. If it is taller than the `ScrollView`, it will be scrollable.

Here is the solution for your example:

```html
<Page class="page dark">

    <ScrollView backgroundColor="red">

        <FlexboxLayout 
            flexDirection="column" 
            justifyContent="space-between" 
            alignItems="stretch" 
            backgroundColor="blue"
        >
            <Label backgroundColor="green">Top Label</Label>

            <StackLayout backgroundColor="green">
                <Label backgroundColor="purple">Label A</Label>

                <Label backgroundColor="purple">Label B</Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</Page>
```